# Prevent webcam light from illuminating when accessing microphone in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, webcam, microphone

I'm writing a small audio recorder component in Silverlight 4. It works fine, but I've noticed that when I'm recording audio, the light on my webcam turns on indicating that the camera is active.

While **I** know that I'm not doing anything insidious with the webcam, my users would have every right to be suspicious.  Is it possible to tell Silverlight that I'm only interested in microphone access and not activate the webcam?

FWIW here's how I'm accessing the mic:

```
private CaptureSource _source = new CaptureSource();
private MemoryAudioSink _sink;  // Inherits from AudioSink. Doesn't do much more 
                                // than store PCM audio stream in memory

private void Record_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (( CaptureDeviceConfiguration.AllowedDeviceAccess || 
          CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess() ) && 
        _source.State == CaptureState.Stopped)
    {
        _sink = new MemoryAudioSink();
        _sink.CaptureSource = _source;
        _source.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CaptureSource will frequently grab the default video input device, even if you don't tell it to. Though you aren't using the camera, Silverlight is indeed accessing it. Hopefully, MS will fix this odd behavior in a later version of Silverlight.

In the meantime, just explicitly set VideoCaptureDevice to null:

```
var _audioCaptureSource = new CaptureSource {VideoCaptureDevice = null};
```

Comment: I'm miles from this project so I can't verify this is correct. If I get a chance I'll try it out. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on the webcam driver - Silverlight would have no control over this.

Comment: When I record audio with Sound Recorder, the light does not illuminate. So I fear there's an oversimplification going on in Silverlight instead.

Comment: Are you sure you're recording from the webcam in Sound Recorder?

Comment: I'm not trying to record audio from the webcam, I'm trying to record it from the default sound device. My webcam is integrated and doesn't have a microphone, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing its related to your use of `CaptureSource`. Microsoft's [web site claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.audiosink.capturesource%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) that:

> Silverlight 4 APIs only use
>   CaptureSource in a video scenario
>   where audio may not be relevant.

Is there a way to get audio without creating your own CaptureSource?